# Is it possible to have a setup.py instead of a SConstruct?

Tags: scons

I am taking a close look at Scons and something smells. SCons uses `SConstruct` files as base configuration file. This configuration file is a Python file but:

- It does not have the `.py` extension
- It does not have any `import` directives
- It is not possible to have auto-completion from IDEs

It it possible to use a variant of the `SConstruct` file where I could find something like the following?

```
# build.py
import scons
env = scons.Environment() 
env.Program('foo')
```

Comment: *SConstruct*s are regular Python files. You can import stuff as usual, so I don't know what your second point is about, please clarify. For the other two points: You can name the top-level *SConstruct* anything you like, but then have to call "scons -f MySConstruct.py" instead. I guess this is more an issue of "How do I get the filename SConstruct detected as Python file in my IDE"?

Comment: I mean if I open SConstruct in PyCharm, it will not recognize `Program` because I need to import a package first. I don't know what I should import first. In other words I claim that `SConstruct` is not a regular Python file. It is a Python snippet without any proper header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be not simple (but possible) to do what you're asking. SConscripts are plain python, however the globals available in the context of SConstruct or SConscripts are carefully constructed.

Any user can add methods and also pass python objects into the SConscripts via Export() or exports (in a SConscript call).

That said try:

```
from SCons.Script import *
```

That should get you some of what you're looking for.

The fact that Pycharm cannot find the symbols in question doesn't mean the it is not a plain python file.

Additionally I'm not sure how the subject of your question relates to the contents of your question. Typically setup.py is a file to build packages ala setuptools and install via pip (or similar).

Sure you can build whatever you are trying to build with setuptools, it will likely be harder to do, but that said if you get it to work, perhaps easier to upload and distribute via pypi

p.s. It's SCons not Scons.